# continuously differentiable map is conformal?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ is a continuously differentiable map on the unit disc and for all $P$ with euclidean distance $R<1$ we know that $\frac{|f(P)-f(0)|}{|P-0|} = \frac{|f(P)|}{|P|} = 1$. (That follows beacuse f pulls back the pair $(\mathbb{D}, \rho )$ to the pair $(\mathbb{D}, \rho)$ with $\rho $ being the Poincaré Metric $\rho(z) = \frac{1}{1-|z|^2}$ and we assume $f(0)=0$. That means that if $C_r $ is the set of points that have Poincaré distance r from 0, we have $f(C_r)=C_r$ and $C_r$ is a Euclidean circle with Radius $R=\frac{e^{2r}-1}{e^{2r}+1}$ )

Letting $R \to 0^+ $ we conclude that $f$ is conformal at the origin.

Can somenone explain why it follows that f is conformal? Any help is very appreciated! The answer is probably simple but I just don't see it.

Comment: Hint: First, consider the case when $f$ is a linear map.

Comment: Where did you get this from? Is it incomplete? $f(z) =z^2$ is continuously differentiable, and maps the unit disc to itself, but $|f(P)/P|=|P|$, not $1$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan If f is a linear map, $f(x)=ax+b$  and we know that $|f(P)|=|P|$ for all P with $|P|=R$ , we can conclude that $b=0 $and  $|a|=1$ by letting $R \to 0^+ $, right? So f must be a rotation and is conformal?

Comment: @Ovi I am sorry, it was incomplete but i edited it.

Comment: @2212345: Right. But  for the linear maps you should only assume that $\lim_{R\to 0+} |f(P)/P|=0$. Can you make the same conclusion? Now, think how this applies to your original question (use the differentiability assumption on $f$). .